# Can the dead see and know about those alive?

Tags: akhirah

Can those dead know, see, and know-about those alive?

Comment: There is a difference between how the Shia and Sunni Muslims believe in this, according to Shi'it yes although there might be or not also some limitations, but according to Sunni the answer is no. What is obvious is that no one (dead or alive) can know anything unless Allah will let him so: "وَلَا يُحِيطُونَ بِشَيْءٍ مِّنْ عِلْمِهِ إِلَّا بِمَا شَاءَ" [2:255]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The principle is that the dead do not hear the words of the living, because Allaah says (interpretation of the meaning): "… but you cannot hear those who are in graves." [Faatir 35:22] and

"Verily, you cannot make the dead to hear…" [al-Naml 27:80]

-http://islamqa.info/en/ref/763

Similarly the dead person does not know anything about the circumstances of his family, because he is absent from them, in a state of bliss or torment. But Allaah may inform some of the dead of some of the circumstances of their families, but this is not necessarily so.

-http://islamqa.info/en/ref/13183

Comment: Thanks Umar. It's logical, because they would probably suffer in the heaven seeing their family going through all the missery (most people on the planet are living in bad conditions, or at least in my country ;( ). Maybe in USA it is better. I don't know.